# Could not install package 'HighChart" in a .Net webform project

Tags: .net, highcharts, webforms

Could not install package 'HighCharts 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nisar Ahmad, Have you tried to use some different Highcharts versions? Also, please check documentation of the Dotnet wrapper: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/products/dotnet/

Comment: Dear @ppotaczek I have downloaded that dlls and have installed it on my machine but that hasn't removed my error for the following namespaces.

`using Highchart.Core.PlotOptions;
using Highchart.Core.Data.Chart;
using Highchart.Core;`

later on when I install all the new things and install the old Highchart.dll present in my published version. Then the error gone away.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I am not sure if your problem has been resolved?

Comment: Dear @ppotaczek My problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
using Highchart.Core.PlotOptions; 
using Highchart.Core.Data.Chart; 
using Highchart.Core;
```

These were the namespace giving errors.
I got a dll from a published version from my server, named  **Highchart.dll**, and added it as a reference. Then the error has gone.